# prerender.io performance issue

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, prerender

I have setup the pretender.io in AW. There are 2 t2.large ec2 instances sitting inside the load balancer.

For a single request, it is taking about 2-3 s to finish one request.

when I am using jmeter to do the performance testing. the test request is poor:

- total duration:       99
- requests:             151
- requests per second:  1
- response duration (ms)
- min:                43
- average:            5217
- max:                20146
- standard deviation: 3905
- quantiles (ms)
- 10%       92
- 20%     2907
- 30%     3250
- 40%     3565
- 50%     4142
- 60%     4933
- 70%     5447
- 80%     6874
- 90%    10815
- 99%    17062
- 99.9%    17538
- 100.0%    20146 (max. value)
- response status codes

  - 200:                 151 (46.04%)
  - 504:                 177 (53.96%)

54.9% of the request got 504.

and seeing many errors like:

> (node:9631) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Cannot communicate with PhantomJS process: Unknown reason
>
> error: Cannot communicate with PhantomJS process: Unknown reason
>
> Experiencing infinite javascript loop. Killing phantomjs...

what things should I look into prerender or phantom.js to tune it?

1. numbers of nodejs workers?
2. Numbers of iteration to kill phantom.js
3. AWS instance size?

Comment: You probably need to use a bigger AWS instance size. PhantomJS needs lots of CPU/RAM and a t2 instance will throttle you. That being said, 2-3 seconds per request is expected if you are loading a webpage.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. what ec2 instance you recommend? and how about the workers and the numbers of iteration to kill phantom.js?  We would be expecting 100 hits from search bot at peek time.

Comment: m3.medium with 1 worker and default iterations should work well enough for your case.

Comment: in my performance testing, i fire 10 requests per seconds. and manage to get the average response time at 2.5s with 90% under 3.3s.  I am using 2 m4.4x large with a elb in front. and the number of worker is 20. i cached all static resources, e.g css/js.      in same test scenario, if i downgrade the ec2 instance to m4.2x , the average time is 3s with 90% under 3.8s.  and if i downgrade the ec2 instance further , i am some 504 responses.   is there anything i can tune it? prerender/phantom.js looks like really cpu/memory intensive.

Comment: Yeah PhantomJS is very cpu/memory intensive. Try increasing some of the timeouts like https://github.com/prerender/prerender#jschecktimeout and that might help a little. 20 workers is a lot. I'd suggest no more than 1 worker per CPU. Also, you should be caching your pages instead of relying on a fast response time for pages rendered on the fly.

Comment: Thanks again for y our comments.